# how to reload the page if input field is empty

Tags: javascript

I need little help with the function. I want to refresh the page after 10 seconds if the msg(input) field is empty.

At the moment the page is refreshing even I type something in the text field.

```
<input type="text" name="message" id="checkmsg" required />


<script>
    var msg = document.getElementById("checkmsg").value;
    console.log(msg);
    function RefreshPage() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (msg === "") {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }, 10000);
    };
    
    RefreshPage()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the value of the input immediately after the element has been loaded, rather than after 10 seconds. The value at page load is `""`, thus you are always reloaded.

You should instead be getting the value of the input in the `setTimeout` function. Simply move the `msg` declaration inside it:

```html
<input type="text" name="message" id="checkmsg" required />


<script>
  function RefreshPage() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var msg = document.getElementById("checkmsg").value;
      console.log(msg);
      if (msg === "") {
        window.location.reload();
      }
    }, 10000);
  };

  RefreshPage()
</script>
```